# If $f$, $g$ and $f*g$ are all in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, does it follow that $\mathcal{F}(f*g)=\mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g)$?

Tags: integration, analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

If $f$, $g$ and $f*g$ are in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, does it follow that $\mathcal{F}(f*g)=\mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g)$ ?
Here $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

I know that if we assume that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ then $f*g\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and the equality above holds true.

However, if I have only that $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, I was thinking of taking a sequence of functions in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ converging to $f$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and apply the result above but I can't pass to the limit.

This makes me think that maybe there are counterexamples.

Comment: Well, $(1/x)\mathbf{1}_{x > 1}$ is in $L^2(\Bbb{R}) \smallsetminus L^1(\Bbb{R})$.  What happens if you set $f$ and $g$ to this function?  Might not resolve your question but may provide insight into which direction to go...